# How to avoid installing requirements.txt before every stage in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, requirements.txt

I have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` which looks like this:

```
image: "python:3.7"

before_script:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

stages:
  - stageA
  - stageB

stage_a:
  stage: stageA
  script:
  - run_some_python_scripts

stage_b:
  stage: stageB
  script:
  - run_more_python_scripts
```

With this setup, `requirements.txt` is installed before every stage.
I need it installed only once, such that both `stageA` and `stageB` can use.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option I've found that works great if the `requirements.txt` file doesn't change much, is to bake it into your own Docker image.

Another option which I personally don't like as much, is to use a `virtualenv` and then use GitLab's [cache](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) on the `virtualenv`, however this can be a bit slow if there are a lot of `pip` packages.

Comment: This is the best way to do it. For my projects I create a docker container and store it in GitLabs registry: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/